# How can I install Git on FreeBSD after error code 1?

Tags: git, freebsd, ports, gitweb

I want to install Git but it gives me error.

I enter `make clean install` and it says:

```
===>  git-2.1.0 using GITWEB support requires PERL support.
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/ports/devel/git
```

What can I do?

Note: When I first tried to install Git, I didn't choose PERL, and I choose GITWEB. Then it gave me this error above. Now, I cannot get rid of this error.

Comment: which operating system?

Comment: don't you have that as a package in freebsd? :)

Comment: You mean build-in Git in FreeBSD? No. I had to install Ports. Then go to /usr/ports/devel/git and type make clean install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link below, it says for FreeBSD you should be able to install git simply using

```
pkg_add -r git
```

or

```
yum -y install gcc gcc-c++ make gettext-devel expat-devel curl-devel zlib-devel openssl-devel bzip2 readline-devel libpcap-devel git.<arch>
```

Replace `<arch>` with your machine's architecture. (e.g. `git.i386`,`git.i686`,`git.x86_64`)

### Further

- [Git Install](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Git_Install)
- [Installing Git and Gitweb on FreeBSD](http://unix-heaven.org/node/43)

Comment: I'm trying this method "Installing Git and Gitweb on FreeBSD". It gives the error that I have wrote in my question.

Comment: I would try using the yum snippet I posted to ensure you have all the appropriate dependencies.  FreeBSD may not have yum but the equivalent to `yum install` should be `pkg install`

Comment: The note about 'make config' in www.freshports.org/devel/git solved my problem :)

Comment: ***`pkg_add: unknown option -- r`*** and ***`yum: command not found`*** for NetBSD 7.0... Its amazing the BSDs are legendary for security yet their package system is basically broken out of the box...

Comment: @jww `-r` is not necessary.  Just emit it.  If you don't have `yum` [install it](http://yum.baseurl.org).

Comment: yum is not a FreeBSD package installer and it makes no sense to install it when FreeBSD has its own.  In addition, the previously suggested 'pkg_add' has been 'pkg add' with a space for quite some time. Yes, I know this answer is two years old.

Answer (score 14):

Simply do "pkg install git", as root.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `ports`:

```
cd /usr/ports/devel/git 
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo make clean
```